# Publisher extension not returning unwrapped value

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have an extension which takes a publisher and waits until a non-nil value is published before taking its value and returning it for use as an async/await function.

```
extension Publisher {
  func value() async throws -> Output {
    try await self
      .compactMap { $0 }
      .eraseToAnyPublisher()
      .async()
  }
}

enum AsyncError: Error {
  case finishedWithoutValue
}

extension AnyPublisher {
  /// Returns the first value of the publisher
  @discardableResult
  func async() async throws -> Output {
    try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { continuation in
      var cancellable: AnyCancellable?
      var finishedWithoutValue = true
      cancellable = first()
        .sink { result in
          switch result {
          case .finished:
            if finishedWithoutValue {
              continuation.resume(throwing: AsyncError.finishedWithoutValue)
            }
          case let .failure(error):
            continuation.resume(throwing: error)
          }
          cancellable?.cancel()
        } receiveValue: { value in
          finishedWithoutValue = false
          continuation.resume(with: .success(value))
        }
    }
  }
}
```

For some reason, when I use it on an optional `@Published` value, it returns an optional, rather than returning the unwrapped value of it. Since it waits until a non-nil value returns, why isn't it unwrapping it? For example, assuming `foo` is an optional published value:

```
let one = await $foo.value() // Returns an optional
let two = await $foo.compactMap { $0 }.value() // Returns a non-optional
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `compactMap` with function that returns `T?` will produce a publisher that emits type `T`, so `Publisher<T,Error>`.  When you call `value` on it directly the associated type `Output` is `T` so the compiler creates a version of `value` that returns `T`.

By construction the type of `$foo` is a publisher whose associated type `Output` is an optional or `T?`, `Publisher<T?,Error>`, so when you call `value` on that the compiler constructs a function that returns `T?`, an optional.

Inside of `value` you use `compactMap` to strip the optional part away, however, because you've said you want a return `Output`, which is`T?`, the compiler implicitly converts your `T` to a `T?` and returns it.

You can change your `value` function so that it specializes for `Optionals`:

```
    func value<T>() async throws -> T where Output == Optional<T>{
        try await self
          .compactMap { $0 }
          .eraseToAnyPublisher()
          .async()
    }
```

The problem is that `value` will no longer work for non-optional types.  You would need two functions... say `value` and `optValue` to handle the separate types.